# Rotating arrow in maps marker at runtime

Tags: android, maps, marker

I'm programming an Android app using Google's maps API v2.
Basically it displays a marker on a map which represents a moving vehicle. I get the heading and speed of the vehicle from the Internet and want to display a marker that color codes the speed, and has an arrow showing the direction of travel.
At the moment I'm using 8 individual marker images for the different headings.
But I have to use a flat marker now, because if i don't and the map is rotated, obviously the arrow will point in the wrong direction, as it is not rotating according to the map orientation.
Is there any way to draw the direction arrow at runtime when I rotate the map? Or do I just have to stick to using a flat marker?

Answer (score 0):

Store the reference to your FLAT marker at creation.

```
Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                      .position(POSITION)
                      .anchor(0.5,0.5)
                      .flat(true));
```

Then call

```
marker.setRotation(rotation);
```

when you need to update the orientation.  The rotation is measured in degrees clockwise from the default position. When the marker is flat on the map, the default position is North.